# Error installing bootstrap and jquery in angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and i tried to install bootstrap and jquery. I was about to add them on the *styles* in **angular.json** when i noticed they were missing. The computer says it successfully installed them but neither can be seen on the **node_modules** folder. I'm pretty sure i am on the right directory when installing them.

The thing is. i created a project before this and bootstrap and jquery were added successfully. what did i do wrong here?

**Edit**

I reloaded the editor, I looked at the folder itself. It's not there.

Comment: Try reloading the Code Editor. This generally happens from time to time. Reloading the editor should fix it.

Comment: I did that. I even looked at the folder itself. Nothing

Comment: Are you sure you installed the modules at the correct location?

Comment: do i need to go to the node_modules folder to install them or just at the root folder of the project?

Comment: Root of the project.

Comment: thats what i did. so its not the directory. i'm thinking about removing both completely then installing it again.

Answer (score 2):

`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`
add this line in src/styles.css